# How can I use the Icon's from font-awesome on NativeScript?

Tags: angularjs, angular, nativescript, font-awesome

I'm trying to use some font-awesome icons on my app that Im developing on NativeScript I just dont know how to use them.

I have tried some ways like puting the unicode of the icon that I want to use on the hint like (Ex: hint="#f2c0 username") in HTML. I have tried to use the font-family: "FontAwesome,'fontawesome-webfont';" in CSS.

Im trying to put like an user icon on the hint of the TextField.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

create folder name with "fonts"in your app folder download 3 files and move them in fonts folder

```
1. fa-brands-400.ttf
2. fa-regular-400.ttf
3. fa-solid-900.ttf
```

write following css class in app.css

```
.far {
  font-family: Font Awesome 5 Free, fa-regular-400;
}

.fab {
  font-family: Font Awesome 5 Brands, fa-brands-400;
}

.fas {
  font-family: Font Awesome 5 Free, fa-solid-900;
}
```

use in xml :

```
<Button class="btn fas" text="&#xf095;"></Button>
```

Comment: I was seeing a question mark icon at first, until I realized that I needed to change the font-family to be "Font Awesome 5 Pro, ..."